# problem with ref variable C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem at the moment. Right now i have 2 forms : login and main. Each of the form has its own notifyIcon with the contextmenu option of show and exit and everything is working well, i followed this [link](http://progtuts.info/14/your-c-program-in-the-system-tray/) to make it work. As for the login, there are 2 ways in which a user can login using the form itself or remotely ( sending a command to the gsm modem connected to the laptop or pc ). And the main form has a timer and once the timer expires the application will hide the main form and display the login form. My objective right is to synchronise the displaying of forms to achieve the function listed below :

1. When the user login onsite using the form, it should display the main form upon successful login.
2. If the user minimise the main form, and if the timer expires the application should not display the login form to the user rather it should hide the login form in the system tray and show it if the user select it from the tray
3. If the application is not minimise to tray then it should display the login form to the user upon session timeout.

I have done function 1,2 and 3 and it works perfectly fine. I use a ref boolean variable called minimiseToTrayStatus and change the variable accordingly and perform if else check on both login and main form to get the features working. Any changes done on minimiseToTrayStatus will be reflected correctly on the other class as well.

Right now i am trying to implement the features below :

1. Upon receiving a remote login command, if the login command is visible then it should show the main form.
2. Upon receiving a remote login command, if the login command hidden in the tray then it should hide the main form in the tray as well.

The problem i encounter when i am trying to implement the above-mentioned feature 1 and 2 is that once the remote command is received i will try to change the ref variable minimiseToTrayStatus appropiately to get the feature done. And i cannot get the feature to work and upon debugging i realised that once a remote command is received and when the applciation attempts to change the minimiseToTrayStatus. The ref variable being shared between login and main form displays different results ? Like one displays true and the other displays false. My understanding on ref variable is that it should display consistent result throughout the program execution no matter where changes are done on the variable. I need it to display same results that is the reason why i used ref variable. Can someone enlighten me on why the ref variable minimiseToTrayStatus is displaying different results ?

Comment: Who ultimately owns this variable? How is it passed around? Some code would probably help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I realised that when i used the ref variable any changes made on the variable will be reflected on the login class but the variable in the main class still access the previous value which was the main source of the problem. Hence to solve this problem i used a mutator/accessor for the minimiseToTrayStatus variable in the login class and access it directly from the main class hence i will have consistent value for the minimiseToTrayStatus variable throughout. Therefore problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. 
It depends of how do you use it. So without some code example I can't say exactly.

But one way, how a variable could be changed in one place and not be updated in other place is if it happens from different threads and no memory barriers are set around the variable.
See:
http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Memory_Barriers_and_Volatility

In this case, try using lock around the place you change your variable. lock automatically set memory barrier. And dont forget to use some object for lock, that is seen for both of your places. Class of some type could be a solution.

```
   lock(typeof(SomeYourClass)){ ... }
```

Comment: +1 for the willingness to look into my thread and provide some suggestion for me to look at.

Comment: My answer was not about what to lock but about using memory barriers which lock statement guaranties. Moreover there is a good explanation what is good and what is bad to lock in the article I put as guide. Grisha, you a too screw on design. Because if you'd read the question you could see that he uses two places which are most definitively two different classes. So using of some public SyncRoot vs. typeof(SomeYourClass) it is just a matter of a design taste. Design, that is not concerned to the question and illustration I've done.